# Ionic Tab view State provider blank view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework, state

I have a tab view inside of my navigation but the content pages stay blank. I tried lots of different app.config settings but nothing works. I want to have the tab views as separate HTML files so I have to get this working. :/

**index.html (the main page of the app):**

```
<ion-pane>
<ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-title>
      <img class="titleLogo" ng-src="img/headers/logo_tabbar.png" />
    </ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</ion-pane>
```

**home.html (this is the page where you get navigated to):**

```
<ion-view ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<ion-tabs class='tabs-icon-top tabs-light'>
  <ion-tab title="diary" href="#/diary">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-diary"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="report" href="#/report">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-report"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="rewards" href="#/rewards">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-rewards"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="messages" href="#/messages">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-messages"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="settings" href="#/settings">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

**diary.html (for example one of the tabs):**

```
<ion-view view-title="Diary" ng-controller="diaryCtrl">
<ion-content>
    diarytest</br>
    diarytest
</ion-content>
```

**app.js (the config file):**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('welcome',{
    url: '/welcome',
    templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html'
  });
  $stateProvider.state('login',{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
  });
  $stateProvider.state('register',{
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'templates/register.html'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('home',{
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  });
  $stateProvider.state('diary',{
    url: '/diary',
    views:{
      'tab-diary':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/diary.html'
      }
    }
  });
  $stateProvider.state('report',{
    url: '/report',
    views:{
      'tab-report':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/report.html',
        controller: 'reportCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $stateProvider.state('rewards',{
    url: '/rewards',
    views:{
      'tab-rewards':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/rewards.html',
        controller: 'rewardsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $stateProvider.state('messages',{
    url: '/messages',
    views:{
      'tab-messages':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/messages.html',
        controller: 'messagesCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
 $stateProvider.state('settings',{
    url: '/settings',
    views:{
      'tab-settings':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
        controller: 'settingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two things:

- `<ion-view>` tag not closed by corresponding `</ion-view>` closing tag
- `ng-controller="diaryCtrl"` directly declared on ion-view instead of being declared in $stateProvider as:

  'tab-diary':{
      templateUrl: 'templates/diary.html',
      controller: 'diaryCtrl'
    }

However I suggest to check a working Ionic "tabbed" application, for example:

- tabs: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/LGZvvb
- tabs and side menu: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/WrqgNm